# Datetime binding with datatable

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I bind my DataTable with a procedure (in which have datetime column) it will display a date as well as time.

How can I get it to display the date without the time?

[image]

Comment: please mark question if any one feel that it is right

Comment: Please provide your code!

Comment: Use the string format {0:MM-dd-yyyy}

Answer (score 0):

Change Formate in Sqlquery : e.g. `Convert(VARCHAR(10),datefield,103) As ShowDate`

```
select Convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),103) As Todaydate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, where are you displaying these records? If you use for example a  `GridView` with a `BoundField` you can use the [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateColumn" 
        HeaderText="DateColumn" 
        SortExpression="DateColumn" 
        DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

However, that works not only in a `BoundField`s, you can use format strings with `DateTimes` always:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

[Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx)